# A failure occurred while executing com.github.triplet.gradle.play.tasks.CommitEdit$Committer

Tags: flutter, google-developers-console, gradle-play-publisher

trying to publish bundle but i got this error every time

```
> Task :app:publishRelease
```

> Task :commitEditForComDotDigcoderDotTecsiDotHse FAILED
> Committing changes
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':commitEditForComDotDigcoderDotTecsiDotHse'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.github.triplet.gradle.play.tasks.CommitEdit$Committer
> 400 Bad Request
> POST https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.digcoder.tecsi.hse/edits/14074052962661642881:commit
> {
> "code" : 400,
> "errors" : [ {
> "domain" : "global",
> "message" : "Only releases with status draft may be created on draft app.",
> "reason" : "badRequest"
> } ],
> "message" : "Only releases with status draft may be created on draft app.",
> "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }

Comment: I think this might have to do something with the draft status of the app on google play as suggested by the error message. Please have a look here: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/tree/master#quickstart-guide which says that you need to Upload the first version of your APK or App Bundle using the Google Play Console